# openCV in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, opencv, emgucv

im tring to use opencv like in the examples that opencv provide

when i run it in the example (in winform) it works fine but in my website i get this error:

```
The type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' threw an exception.
```

and inner exception:

```
An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)
```

with the stack:

```
at Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.cvLoadImage(String filename, LOAD_IMAGE_TYPE loadType)
at Emgu.CV.Image`2.LoadImageUsingOpenCV(FileInfo file)
at Emgu.CV.Image`2..ctor(String fileName)
```

im using the emgucv windows x64 2.40 version

Answer (score 0):

Download emgu 64 bit version and you need to inistall visual c++ runtime 64 bit

Comment: the installation didnt help me  to solve the error i got in my question

Comment: Maybe HElp you:http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/256772/an-exception-in-using-emgucv

Comment: with winform i dont have this problame it only happen in asp.net

Comment: I too have same problem @roy.d. if you know let me provide link.

Answer (score 0):

i found some solution but its not realy good idea
what i  did was going in visual studio to the project properties to the web section
and check the radio to use local iis webserver.

i guess emgucv found some better help then doing that, why vs2010 in 64bit force you to do it?